# What is best convention for writing induction proofs in latex?

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing some induction proofs for my homework.

What is considered to be best convention for writing these kind of proofs?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Math.SE

Comment: Related? [Any good way to write mathematical induction proof steps in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111412/any-good-way-to-write-mathematical-induction-proof-steps-in-latex)